# Node JS mySQL update multiple rows by joining queries

Tags: mysql, node.js

In my node module I need to update multiple number of rows (number is not fixed) in order to accomplish that I've created a loop which assign values to one array and generate next "UPDATE SET...;" string. So at the end it looks like this:

```
UPDATE rules_cancellation SET period = ?, amount = ?, type = ? WHERE ID
 = ?; UPDATE rules_cancellation SET period = ?, amount = ?, type = ? WHERE ID = ?;
```

And array:

```
[ 111, 111, '%', 27, 222, 222, '£', 28 ]
```

But I receive that error:

```
{ Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
 the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
 right syntax to use near '111, '%', 27, 222, 222, '£', 28, amount = ?,
 type = ? WHERE ID = ?; UPDATE rule' at line 1
```

And my code:

```
            var queryUpdate = '';
            var dataUpdate = [];
            for(var i in cancellation.rule)
            {   
            queryUpdate += "UPDATE rules_cancellation SET period = ?, amount = ?, type = ? WHERE ID = ?; ";
            dataUpdate.push(cancellation.rule[i].daysBefore);
            dataUpdate.push(cancellation.rule[i].fee);
            dataUpdate.push(cancellation.rule[i].type);
            dataUpdate.push(cancellation.rule[i].id);
            }


            connection.query(queryUpdate, dataUpdate, function(err,results){
                        if(err){return console.log(err)}
                        console.log('ok!')

            });
```

Is that an error in my node syntax or query? How can I fix this problem? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you sure that `dataUpdate` holds `[ 111, 111, '%', 27, 222, 222, '£', 28 ]`  and not `[[ 111, 111, '%', 27, 222, 222, '£', 28 ], undefined, undefined, ...]`

Comment: Yes. I've checked it on my console.log. Should I split one big array into smaller ones?

Comment: Could you please verify this by adding `console.log(JSON.stringify(dataUpdate));` right before the `connection.query` and show the result. In general you should avoid to enable `multipleStatements`.